# Peewee jointure not return all selected fields

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I have some trouble using the peewee library. I'm using sqlite database behind my python application combined with peewee to acces the database and on one of my function, i'm retrieving datas depending on the input parameters of my function, it looks like this:

```
def display_characters(self, menu_update: PageView123, emoji: Emoji = None):
        # Characters retrieving
        query = Character.select(Character, fn.Count(Character.id).alias('count'), CharactersOwnership.discord_user_id)
        museum_filter = menu_update.retrieve_hidden_data()
        if museum_filter.category is not None:
            query = query.where(Character.category == museum_filter.category)
        if museum_filter.rarity is not None:
            query = query.where(Character.rarity == museum_filter.rarity)
        if museum_filter.affiliation is not None:
            query = (query.join(CharacterAffiliation)
                     .join(Affiliation)
                     .where(Affiliation.name == museum_filter.affiliation))
        total_characters = query.count()

        # Then we filter on only the owned card
        query = (query.join(CharactersOwnership, on=(CharactersOwnership.character_id == Character.id))
                      .where(CharactersOwnership.discord_user_id == museum_filter.owner.id)
                      .group_by(Character.id)
                      .order_by(Character.name))

        total_owned = query.count()
```

The code itself doesn't speak much, but the thing is that when i'm reaching the last step, the models retrieved are not complete when we enter the condition `if museum_filter.affiliation is not None:`.
To describe my issue, here is what it looks like:

[image: Error]

Any idea why the model that result from the query is not complete?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to explicitly call .join_from() specifying source and dest table, since peewee's "join context" may be hurting you rather than helping you. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#joining-multiple-tables -- Alternatively, at the end of the affiliation block call .switch(Character) to reset the join context to character.

Additionally, you need to explicitly select() all the columns you want retrieved. Just joining on additional tables does not imply selecting the data out of them.

Comment: @coleifer, thanks a lot man! Using "join_from" to keep the context did the trick, could you maybe add your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to explicitly call `.join_from()` specifying source and dest table, since peewee's "join context" may be hurting you rather than helping you. Doc here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#joining-multiple-tables

Alternatively, at the end of the affiliation block call `.switch(Character)` to reset the join context to character. Additionally, you need to explicitly `select()` all the columns you want retrieved. Just joining on additional tables does not imply selecting the data out of them